# Django only returns last row of dict in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to return the values from a Dict in Django.

My `views.py` prints the the correct data in the terminal when doing a GET-request to my page, however, in my template I only get the last line of the dictionary.

I have tried looping the dict in my template and all sorts of combinations but I can't seem to make it work. Am I missing something? For instance, in the template below I print the entire dict. But it still only prints the last row somehow.

**views.py**

```
fruits = [
    'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']

for fruit in fruits:

    price_change = historical_prices['price_change'][::-1]
    low_price = 0
    for day in price_change:
        if day < -0.1:
            low_price += 1
        else:
            break
        
    if low_price >= 0:
        ls_dict = {'fruit': fruit, 'low_price': low_price}
        print(ls_dict)

return render(request, "prices/index.html", {
    "ls_dict": ls_dict,
    })
```

**Template**

```
<p>{{ ls_dict }}</p>
```

**Template output**

```
{'fruit': 'Orange', 'low_price': 1}
```

**Correct print which views.py produces**

```
{'fruit': 'Apple', 'low_price': 1}
{'fruit': 'Banana', 'low_price': 3}
{'fruit': 'Orange', 'low_price': 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `print()` seems correct, but you are just overriding the variable over and over again, thus `ls_dict` will only be the set with the last iteration of the `for` loop.

You can test this by `print(ls_dict)` outside of  the `for`-loop

Try the following:

```
ls_list = []
for fruit in fruits:

    price_change = historical_prices['price_change'][::-1]
    low_price = 0
    for day in price_change:
        if day < -0.1:
            low_price += 1
        else:
            break
        
    if low_price >= 0:
        ls_dict = {'fruit': fruit, 'low_price': low_price}
        ls_list.append(ls_dict)

return render(request, "prices/index.html", {
    "ls_list": ls_list,
    })
```